# Php-code that works on one server but not on another. Why?

Tags: php, google-maps

I made a short code to calculate distance using Google Maps API. My problem is that the code works fine on one server, but not on another. It is the axact same code copied from one place to antother. I can't figure out whats wrong.
Can anyone help me?

```
$server="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=".$from.",Sweden&destination=".$to.",Sweden";
if($stream = fopen( $server,r)){
$klart=json_decode(stream_get_contents($stream),true);
fclose($stream);
$distans = $klart['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance'][text];
 $kilometer=split(" ",$distans);
$km = $kilometer[0];
$kostnad = $km * ((2.1*1.15)*1.25)/5;
}
```

Thank you!
Anders

Edit 1: Thank you all for your comments. It seems that it was a javascript that interfered with the html-form. I've added a script to autocomplete the cities (variables $to and $from). When I comment out the javascript, the php code works fine.

Comment: Error logs? Error Messages? PHP version? You've not provided enough of anything for anyone to help you.

Comment: there are a few errors being generated when I run this. undefined constant `r` in `if($stream = fopen( $server,r)){` ~ should be 'r' and `split` is deprecated

Comment: So dump the results line by line; where does it go wrong? Or use a debugger.

Comment: To expand on @jeroen's comment, when doing basic debugging of code, if you have an "if", put an "else" to check for failure.  Use "echo" statements after assignments and before functions to make sure that values are indeed what you expect them to be.  Put them also *after* the function calls to make sure the function is returning the value expected.  And of course, a good professional practice is to design the code with all these checks & verifications built into the system....

Comment: The code works fine an returns the correct result. Its only problem is the usage of the [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) that is deprecated since PHP 5.3 and completely removed in PHP 7.0. Replace it with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and it should work and stop issuing warnings.

Comment: You need to wrap the second parameter for `fopen()` in quotes. That's why you are getting an undefined constant error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse the delay in adding commentary, something urgent cropped up and I had to leave. Initially when I ran the code there were several errors thrown - aside from the lack of `$from` & `$to` there were two undefined constants ~ namely `r` and `text`

```
$from='malmo';
$to='stockholm';

$server="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=".$from.",Sweden&destination=".$to.",Sweden";

/* the mode `r` needs to be quoted */
if($stream = fopen( $server,'r')){

    $klart=json_decode(stream_get_contents($stream),true);
    fclose($stream);
    /* the field `text` also needs to be quoted - unless it really is a constant defined elsewhere */

    $distans = $klart['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text'];
    /* as `split` is now deprecated, use preg_split & split string on a space `\s` */
    $kilometer=preg_split('@\s@',$distans);
    $km = $kilometer[0];
    $kostnad = $km * ((2.1*1.15)*1.25)/5;

    echo $kostnad;
}

outputs:
369.495
```

Comment: Maybe an explanation as to why this would work?